plymouth + xterm + sudo: not work...why?
i create file sh, i click file sh will start to executive. but Xterm not work to run plymouthd... instead kdesu is worked to run plymouthd..but i want to use xterm.. maybe i missing something parameter..
this is KDESU (works)
#!/bin/bash
kdesu -c "sudo plymouthd; plymouth --show-splash; sleep 10; plymouth quit"

this is xterm (not work)
#!/bin/bash
xterm -geometry 130x15 -fg Plum1 -bg Purple4 -fa 'Monospace' -fs 10 -e 'sudo plymouthd; plymouth --show-splash; sleep 10; plymouth quit'

I checked in google but nothing find..damn...

What do you mean by doesn't work? Can you run plymouthd without typing sudo password? What does it say on the screen?

https://ibb.co/3CHyqJc

kdesu open dialog for password of sudo and start plymouth splash preview.. instead xterm open window for password of sudo but there are messages but not start plymouth splash preview..for this reason: xterm not work..?

see here screen record: https://sendvid.com/n10h2mz9    note: kdesu works screen is black is worked because open other runlevel..but xterm nothing..
